# Bulk Product out of stock Issue at once

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change product inventory from in stock to out of stock at once. how will do?
Bcoz, one by one takes lot of time, want to save time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `catalog > Mange Products` select the products you want to make `out-of-stock` , then you can see `update attributes` option at right. click on `update attributes` then you will redirect to new page there you can see an option `Inventory` in left side , click on that and than you can see option `out-of-stock` at the end , just select that and save it as in below image....

**step 1)** Catalog > Manage > Products [ Note : Make sure you select only the products you want to make out-of-stock ]

[image]

**step 2)**

[image]

Comment: I have 30 Products, i  don't want change manually one by one, want to change at once.

Comment: @AtulKumar you can do it by selecting those 30 products and make it by following answer....

Comment: @AtulKumar please accept answer.....

Answer (score 0):

[image: Select the products to make out of stock, select update attributes from the drop down on top and click submit]

Then you will get a page like product edit in that select tab inventory and then change stock status

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: I have one more question, i am new in magneto and i have knowledge of(html, css, photo shop and bootstrap). now, i manage whole e commerce multi designer fashion website. today, i create GST  Tax Classes as per indian law for different - different products(ex: footwear, carpets, sarees, jewelery, dresses), but  i am confusing if somebody place order on website from out of country, GST will applicable or not for international orders.

Comment: Tax will be applied based on the shipping address. So if an user places order from outside country the tax won't be applied if you have created the rule like that. You can check the effect by place order with outside address. if not solved create a new ticket. accept any one of the answer which helped you.

Comment: You are saying GST Tax will apply  only in india and out of country shipping charging will apply?

Comment: I have product category of juuties and clothes. i want to customize first all jutties display after that display rename clothes or first display all clothes after that display rename jutties on same category page.

Comment: One More issue, i create GST Rule. it's working fine. but when someone placed order, i want to change word 'Tax' into 'GST' . can you help how will change.